# How to get all possible combinations to make a string with a dictionary

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a dictionary, let's say D = {"A", "B", "AB"} and a string S = "ABAB". How can I compute the **number** of possible combinations to make a string with a dictionary? The solution to the case above would be **4** for example: (AB)(AB), (AB)(A)(B), (A)(B)(AB), (A)(B)(A)(B).

Comment: Is this from an online judge/programming contest? Can you provide a link to the original problem statement?

Comment: @MukulGupta This is an assignment and the original problem is in german.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the dictionary D = {w<sub>1</sub>, w<sub>2</sub>, ..., w<sub>n</sub>} where the w<sub>i</sub> are dictinct words. Let S be a string.

Let Count(S, D) be a function that returns the number of possible combinations of forming S using the words of the dictionary D. Count(S, D) is defined as follows.

1. If S is the empty string, return 1.
2. Set c = 0.
3. For every word w in D, if S does not start with w, continue with the next word. Otherwise set c = c + Count(S - w, D) where S - w is the string S with w removed from the start.
4. Return c.

A dynamic programming implementation can easily be derived by storing previous results in a map of strings to their counts. In step 2, before iterating over all words, we check if S is in the map, and return its count, if it is. In step 4, before returning c, we store S in the map with its count.

Comment: Let me know if this does what you expected.

Comment: This is the canonical solution for a NDFSM (Non-Deterministic Finite-State Machine) to parse the given "grammar".

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll try to implement this dynamicly.

Comment: Ah you wanted a dynamic programming imlpementation. The question did not really ask for that, but I see now that you have the `dynamic-programming` tag.

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
def parse_all(sent, so_far, lexicon):
    """
    sent      remaining sentence to parse
    so_far    word divisions on this branch
    lexicon   dictionary
    """

    # Base case: empty string
    if not sent:
        print(so_far)
        return

    # Recursion
    for word in lexicon:
        if sent.startswith(word):
            parse_all(sent[len(word):], so_far + '|' + word, lexicon)


lexicon = ["A", "B", "AB"]
parse_all("ABAB", "", lexicon)
```

Output:

```
|A|B|A|B
|A|B|AB
|AB|A|B
|AB|AB
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive answers are correct but not efficient. What you need to do is **dynamic programming**.
The sub problems are the number of combination for each string S[i...j], and the solution to the sub problem is to sum the values for (S[i...j] - w) for every w that is a prefix to S[i...j] (w removed from the start).

Comment: This is helping me a lot, thank you. I'll try to implement this.